# Float point instructions

Tags: assembly, converters, mips

Probably I don't know how to use instructions in floating point. I wanna read a float, make some operations and print the result as float again, but SPIM gives me an error here `mov.s $f0, $v0`. I think whenever use floating point instructions, I have to give two `$f` registers, right? But how can I copy something that is in `$v0` because syscall wants that?

This is my code

```
    .data 0x10010000
prompt:     .asciiz "Write 0 to °C -> °F\Write 1 for °F ->°C;\n"
ctof:       .asciiz "Degree in Fahrenheit: "
ftoc:       .asciiz "Degree in Celsius: "
error:      .asciiz "Error: write 0 o 1\n\n"

    .text 0x400000
main:       la $a0, prompt
            li $v0, 4
            syscall         #print prompt

            li $v0, 5
            syscall         #read integer

            beq $v0, 0, c_to_f
            beq $v0, 1, f_to_c

            la $a0, error
            li $v0, 4
            syscall         #print error

            j main

c_to_f:     la $a0, ftoc
            li $v0, 4
            syscall         #print ftoc

            li $v0, 6
            syscall         #read degree as float

            mov.s $f0, $v0
            mul.s $f0, $f0, 9.0
            div.s $f0, $f0, 5.0
            add.s $f0, $f0, 32.0

            la $a0, ctof
            li $v0, 4
            syscall         #print ctof

            move $f12, $f0
            li $v0, 2
            syscall         #print result

            li $v0, 10
            syscall         #exit
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

System call 6 (`read_float`) returns the value in `$f0`, not `$v0`. So your `mov.s $f0, $v0` is unnecessary since you already have the value in `$f0`.

If you *do* have an integer value in a GPR and want to convert it to floating-point and place it in a floating-point register then you can do that as follows:

```
mtc1 $v0,$f0     # Move the value of $v0 into $f0
cvt.d.w $f12,$f0 # Convert the integer value in $f0 into a double-precision
                 # floating-point value and place the result in $f12
```

Consult *MIPS32™ Architecture For Programmers
Volume II: The MIPS32™ Instruction Set* if you want to read more about the `cvt` and `mtc1` instructions.

Comment: What about pseudoinstructions `mul.s $f0, $f0, 9.0` and the other two below? Spim gives me a syntax error. Doesn't use `$at` to convert the instruction? Should I put the constant in a `$f` register using `li.s $f1, 9.0`?

Comment: SPIM might not support those pseudo-instructions. You should be able to use `li.s` like you suggested. Note that if you use single-precision floats in the rest of your code you should probably use `cvt.s.w` instead of `cvt.d.w` when converting integers to floating-point.